# Accessing $(this).next and slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery

When choosing the option *initials? Yes* the `Textarea.someClass` should slide down and show itself. I have to use `$(this)` because there will be several of these select options and text areas on the page.

I've tried numerous variations of the code below, including using `sibling()` but it is not working.

```
<select class="initials">
<option value="no">Initials? No</option>
<option value="yes">Initials? Yes</option>  
</select><br/>
<textarea class="someClass">Put instructions here </textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('select.initials').change(function(){
     theVal = $(this).val();
    // alert(theVal); WORKING
    if(theVal == 'yes') {
        $(this).next('textarea.someClass').slideDown();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a br in between, so your `next()` doesn't pick the textarea that is next to the br. so try:

```
$(this).next().next('textarea.someClass').slideDown(); //
```

or use the below so that it doesn't what ever number of elements comes in between.

```
$(this).nextUntil('textarea.someClass').next().slideDown();
```

Or just give your textarea a display:block.

```
.someClass{
    display:block;
}
```

and hide the textarea startup and remove the br in between.

Also you forgot a closing brace in your script.

```
$('select.initials').change(function(){
     theVal = $(this).val();
    // alert(theVal); WORKING
    if(theVal == 'yes') {
        $(this).next('textarea.someClass').slideDown();
    } //<--- Here
});
```

You can also simply the script if you are trying to toggle to:

```
$(this).next('textarea.someClass').slideToggle(this.value === "Yes");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DySxS/)**

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Rd7Wh/)</kbd>

```
$('select.initials').change(function () {
    theVal = $(this).val();
    // alert(theVal); WORKING
    if (theVal == 'yes') {
        $(this).next().next('textarea.someClass').hide().slideDown();
    }
});
```

Use

```
$(this).next().next('textarea.someClass')
```

and you are not closing your `.change` event properly you have typos there